# Using external variable in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue + Webpack single page app. Webpack in fairly common config generates a bundle with different chunks, app, and vendor js. I am know putting this spa static dist in a Docker container. What I would like to know if there is a way to add a js  after the bundle is already created and packed (dist dir) where I can put some variables which are specific to each deployment I make. I would like to use this to  change the api url.  Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `appconfig.json` in your `dist` folder and fetch it with `axios` in your `/src/main.js`, for example:

```
// your imports here
// ...

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    axios.get('./appconfig.json')
        .then(response => {
            const config = response.data;
            const host = axios.defaults.baseURL = config.baseURL;
            // other production configs

            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                router,
                components: {App},
                template: '<App/>'
            });
        });
} else {
    // dev configs

    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router,
        components: {App},
        template: '<App/>'
    });
}
```

Changing properties in `appconfig.json` changes settings inside the app after the user refreshes the page without having to rebuild or restart server.